# I keep getting TypeScript Error 2322 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I keep getting ts error

```
(Type 'string | { englishResults: {}; "": any; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type '{ englishResults: {}; "": any; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'englishResults' does not exist in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.ts(2322))
```

while creating an array from data (object) I get from localStorage. I wanted to create an array from the object using `Object.keys()` function. But the returned array keeps triggering the above error. I have tried different methods to solve the issue but to no avail. I am stuck.

Here is the code

```
const Admin = () => {
  const { adminId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [results, setResults] = useState(false);
  const [studentEnglishResults, setStudentEnglishResults] = useState({});
  const [englishResults, setEnglishResults] = useState({});

  if (localStorage.length > 0) {
    setResults(true);
    setStudentEnglishResults(JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("englishAnswers")!
    ));
    setEnglishResults(Object.keys(studentEnglishResults));
  }

  const adminUser = adminUsers.find(
    (adminUser) => adminUser.adminId === adminId
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (adminUser?.adminId !== adminId) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, []);

  const clearResult = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
  };

  const backToLogin = () => {
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-gray-400 mx-auto w-3/4 p-3 mt-5">
        <p className="capitalize font-serif">
          <span className="font-bold">Admin</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className="shadow-md shadow-gray-500 w-2/4 mx-auto p-5">
        <table className="table-auto border-collapse border w-full">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="text-left">Question</th>
              <th className="text-left">Answer</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            //the error comes from this line
            { results ? {englishResults.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td className="">{item}</td>
                  <td>{(studentEnglishResults as any)[item]}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })} : ''}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

Comment: I don't think any of us have memorized TS compiler messages based on their number code... what error *message* are you getting?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error message. Thanks

Comment: First of all `useState` doesn't update variable immediately, so  `studentEnglishResults` will be old here - `setEnglishResults(Object.keys(studentEnglishResults));`. Also, casting to `any` hardly ever solves any problems, but generates multiple new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign types at the same time you use `useState`. For example, assuming `englishResults` is an array of type string array, you can do this:

```
const [studentEnglishResults, setStudentEnglishResults] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

Similarly, assuming `studentEnglishResults` is an object with strings as keys and strings for values, you can tell that to TypeScript like this:

```
const [studentEnglishResults, setStudentEnglishResults] = useState<{[key: string]: string}>();
```

or to make it more readable,

```
type StudentEnglishResults = {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const Admin = () => {
    const [studentEnglishResults, setStudentEnglishResults] = useState<StudentEnglishResults>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: `studentEnglishResults[item]` values are all type string.

Comment: Thank you it worked. The error is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

This defines `englishResults` as an object:

```
const [englishResults, setEnglishResults] = useState({});
```

But you try to use it like an array by calling `map` on it. I see that you're trying to convert the object to an array with `Object.keys`, but you can't dynamically change the type of something In Typescript, you will get a lot of type errors if you do.

Also this is syntactically incorrect code:

```
results ? {englishResults.map(...)} : ""
```

You should not use braces here.

Comment: I understand. But changing the type to array like `const [englishResults, setEnglishResults] = useState([]);` also trigger this error Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345). That's why I got confused. I am honestly not good with typescript I can see how it can save me a lot of headache along the way. Thanks

Comment: You need to use `useState<string[]>([])`